# Spring - Intercept response from another bean by exception handler

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have two `@RestController`s - (A and B) and registered `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. Is it possible (and how to do it) to call from `A` and get a response from `B` after the exception handler is applied?

Example:

1. User rest call `A`
2. `A` calls `B` with `getPerson`
3. `B` throws exception `NotFound`
4. `NotFound` is handled by an exception handler, transforming `ResponseEntity` and put 400 status
5. `B` finally return exception `ResponseEntity`
6. `A` gets 400 status from `B`
7. `A` can get this 400 and do something with it

Simple `@Autowired` is not working.

Snippet:

A:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class A {

    private final B b;

    @Autowired
    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @PostMapping(
        value = "persons",
        consumes = "application/json",
        produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<List<StatusResponse<Person>>> addPersons(final List<Person> persons) {
        final List<StatusResponse<Person>> multiResponse = new ArrayList<>();
        for(final Person p: persons) {
            final ResponseEntity<Person> response = b.addPerson(person);
            multiResponse.add(new StatusResponse<>(
                response.getStatusCode(), response.getMessage(), response.getBody()
            ));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.MULTI_STATUS).body(multiResponse);
    }

}
```

B:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class B {

    @PostMapping(
        value = "person",
        consumes = "application/json",
        produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Person> addPerson(final Person person) {
        accessService.checkAccess();
        return ResponseEntity.status(201).body(
            logicService.addPerson(person)
        );
    }

}
```

Handler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public final class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleApiException(final MyException exception, final WebRequest webRequest) {
        //logic
        return afterLogic;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you put some code snippet?

Comment: More or less it will be like I updated.

Comment: In which line MyException may be thrown? Is it logicService.addPerson(person)?

Comment: MyException can be accessException from accessService, or notfoundexception/badrequestexception etc. from logic service.

Comment: ByeBye Probably your missing "@Component or @Service " annotation. please check annotation on accessService or logic Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is not possible to get control back to controller from exception handler which is invoke after handling its method.** Your current flow looks like this `call A.addPersons` -> `invoke B.addPerson` -> `B throws exception` -> `exception is propagate to A controller` and it's save as dispatchException to futher processing in DispatcherServlet after handling controller method (not ResponseEntity with status 400) -> exception is handled with MyExceptionHandler. From this place you cannot back to controller.

I'm not sure what you want to do it with this exception in controller but solution may look like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/resources")
public class AController {

    private BService service;

    @Autowired
    public AController(BService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        ResponseEntity<String> result = service.test();
        if (result.hasBody()) {
            //doSomething
        }

        return result; //or list like you did
    }
}

@Service
public class BService {

    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.status(201).body(getResponse()); //this always throws exception. It's just for purpose of example
        } catch (CustomException ex) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(400).build();
        }

    }

    private String getResponse() {
        throw new CustomException("Not OK!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, exception handling has many outcomes and simple mapping it in controller will produce many code duplication. Okay, it seems that is is not possible.

Comment: What do you want to do with this exception in A controller? Just add StatusResponse with status 400 to multiResponse?

Comment: more or less - yes, but I need a specific status response which comes from exception and message.

Comment: The problem is that exception mapper is mapping many different exceptions to MyException based on type. I don't want to create big multpile caches in controller A.

Comment: What do you mean by exception mapper?

Comment: Check if this is resolving your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32445360/1694996
If not, please describe it in more detail why.

Comment: It is not working because it doesn't intercept between two controllers. As you said it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

forward is like to redirect but happens entirely on a server side; the Servlet container forwards the same request to the target URL; the URL won’t change in the browser.
in spring you can do it like this, and you can pass attribute :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class YourController {

    @GetMapping("/forward")
    public ModelAndView redirectWithUsingForwardPrefix(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("attribute", "forward");
        return new ModelAndView("forward:/redirectedUrl", model);
    }
}
```